# Size of nested array in aggregation projection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a "Quiz" model, where each quiz document has some questions and an array of answers in them.

1. **Example document structure (Quiz.findOne()):**

```
_id: ObjectId("611478ac34dde61f28dbe4db"),
name: "Quiz 1",
questions: [
    {
       text: "Question 1",
       answers: ["a", "b", "c"],
    },
    {
       text: "Question 2",
       answers: ["m", "n", "o", "p"],
    },
    ...
    ...
    {
       text: "Question 1000",
       answer: ["a", "c", "e", "f"],
    },
 ]
```

2. I am selecting some particular questions by index, using MongoDB aggregation.
   **Aggregation code:**

```
Quiz.aggregate([
                {
                    $match: { _id: "611478ac34dde61f28dbe4db" },
                },
                {
                    $addFields: {
                        questions: {
                            $map: {
                                input: [0, 1], //Choosing the questions at index 0 and 1 (can be any other index)
                                as: "i",
                                in: {
                                    $arrayElemAt: ["$questions", "$$i"],
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    },
                },
                {
                    $project: {
                        "questions.answers": 1,
                    },
                },
            ])
```

3. **Output comes as:**

```
[{
_id: "611478ac34dde61f28dbe4db",
questions: [
    {
       answers: ["a", "b", "c"],
    },
    {
       answers: ["m", "n", "o", "p"],
    },
 ]
}]
```

4. How can I convert this output to show only the "$size" of the array?
   **Expected output:**

```
[{
_id: "611478ac34dde61f28dbe4db",
questions: [
    {
       answers: 3, //Had 3 answers: a, b, c
    },
    {
       answers: 4, //Had 4 answers: m, n, o, p
    },
 ]
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add new aggregation stage where you can use `$map` and `$size` pipeline operators, like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "questions": {
        $map: {
          input: "$questions",
          as: "question",
          in: {
            answers: {
              $size: "$$question.answers"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/0eyAlMWai0A

Comment: Works! Appreciate your help.